# Weird behavior of awk

Tags: awk

Why do I get only "cat" when I run

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  animal[three] = "hen"
  animal[two]   = "dog"
  animal[one]   = "cat"
  for (var in animal) {
    print animal[var]
  }
}
```

??

Shouldn't it print "hen", "dog" and "cat"?

Comment: Missing a `'` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Indices to awk arrays can either be numeric (as in a traditional array) or strings (an associative array).  So you can either do

```
animal[1] = "cat"
```

or

```
animal["one"] = cat
```

However, if you do

```
animal[one] = cat
```

awk will try to find a variable called 'one', fail, and effectively do this:

```
animal[""] = cat
```

So in your program, all three animals are assigned to `animal[""]`, so you end up with only one element in your array.

If you put `one`, `two` and `three` in quotes, your code will work as you expect.

Comment: Good one! You can also indicate by printing `print animal[var], "-"var"-"`. `var` is empty, `-` to show where it starts and where it ends.